# Beta decay breaks conservation of momentum?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, momentum, radiation

Just considering the decay of a free neutron, the change in rest mass, .732-ish MeV, leaves as kinetic energy of the electron and neutrino. Doesnt this break conservation of momentum since the neutron has no momentum? What am I missing, is there really a mass-energy-momentum conservation and momentum conservation on its own doesnt exist for beta decay?

In math, before = after, is

pn = pe + pp + pv

Or

E + p = sum of E + sum of p

Or something else?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, n-p is 1.2 but n-p-e is .732

Comment: So this is the kinetic energy of the three decay products.

Comment: The sum of it yeah

Comment: The nucleus can also get kinetic energy. You have too many variables to have a unique solution (hence the question for some time if the neutrino had mass).

Comment: @JonCuster, there is no request for a unique solution in the question. Anna v has answered my question clearly without a unique solution. Note that I asked the reader to consider the free neutron so that there is no nucleus involved. Aside from a hydrogen ion 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** after the question was edited to include the proton in the decay products

Momentum is a vector quantity and the f[our vector algebra has to be used](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) when discussing decays and conservation laws at particle level. The equation for the momentum is

$P_xn=p_xp+p_xν+p_xe$

$P_yn=p_yp+p_yν+p_ye$

$P_zn=p_zp+p_zν+p_ze$

If in the center of mass of the neutron, when P is equal to zero, conservation requires for the sum to be zero.

and for energy

En=Ep+Eν+Ee

Where E is the total energy in the system, all to be computed with the [four vector algebra](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html)  representing the particles . The "length" of the four vector is the invariant mass of the particle it represents.

Answer (score 1):

Energy and momentum are definitely conserved in beta decay. Note that [free neutron decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_neutron_decay) is different from
[nuclear beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) where the original neutron is not free and is bound to a nucleus.

Also, in the decay $$n\rightarrow p+e^-+\bar\nu$$ the kinetic energy of the resulting proton and nucleus (in the beta-decay version) must also be taken into account and not just the "kinetic energy of the electron and neutrino". You'll find that energy and momentum *are* conserved (in either case).

Comment: Only considering a free neutron. Im not finding moment alone is conserved. The e has momentum after rest mass is converted into kinetic energy, and before decay there is no momentum.

Comment: @Jason The proton only picks up a tiny amount of kinetic energy because it's so massive compared to the two leptons.

Comment: @PM2Ring, doggone, vector sum is conserved, I was only thinking of the magnitudes.

Comment: @Jason Yes, momentum is always a vector. ;) Although the velocity of the proton (or nucleus) is tiny, it was still measurable in the early days of atomic physics. And it was noticed that the KE & momentum of the nucleus & electron didn't *quite* make sense. So the neutrino was invented to make energy & momentum balance correctly. Decades later, we were finally able to detect neutrinos, but that's still *really* difficult.

Comment: New rule, I downvote for "Trust me" answers  but will flip vote easily